# Query Google searches in Java?

Tags: java

Say I search for something on Google and I want to return the title and descriptions of the search given. Also I want to incorporate services like Google maps because sometimes when a product is searched on Google, the location of the store it is sold in is also displayed. How would I return that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would start with the [gdata-java-client](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/) api. It integrates with Google's services.

Use the Google Base Data API for searches and the Google Maps Data API for maps integration.